# Como quitar la hora a una fecha en JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema ya que estoy recibiendo una fecha de la forma que se ve en la imagen y yo solo ocupo la pura fecha sin la hora, la hora me esta causando conflicto en lo que estoy haciendo y quiero eliminarla si es posible y no puedo cambiar la forma de la base de datos por eso lo quiero hacer Js.

[image: De esta forma me llega la Fecha]

Comment: ¿Siempre te va a devolver la T en esa misma posición de la cadena?

Comment: Si, siempre me la devuelve así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa slice: `cadena.slice(inicioTrozo[, finTrozo])`

```javascript
const cadena = "1999-10-23T00:00:00"; 
    
const fixCadena = cadena.slice(0, -9);

console.log(fixCadena); 

// output: 
// "1999-10-23T"
```

De ahí en más puedes convertirlo en datetime con `Date.parse()`.

> Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho.